# Python BCPY Importing CSV into SQL Server : how do I add a text qualifier for commas within quotes

Tags: python, sql-server, csv, bcp, qualifiers

I am using Python BCPY to import a `.CSV` file into SQL Server, and this does it really fast. As this imports it by commas, I am getting a mismatch in data because I have columns that have commas in between quotes. Is there something in BCPY that will allow me to do this or a workaround? Thanks for the responses in advance

Comment: If the commas are quoted, they shouldn't be interpreted as field separators.  Post a sample of the data and also the code you're using to import it.

Comment: Can you use a different delimiter?  BCP isn't as fluent in CSV formats as the Python csv module is.  If you can write (or rewrite) the file to use `|` as the delimiter, you can avoid the problem.